# How to run an ansible playbook on a specific vagrant host

Tags: ansible, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrantfile which creates 3 servers. I have two ansible playbooks. playbook1 should be executed on every server first. The second playbook2 should only be executed on server1 and not on server2 and server3.

How can I manage this with my Vagrantfile?

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64" 

  config.vm.define "server1" do |server1|
    //
  end

  config.vm.define "server2" do |server2|
    //
  end

  config.vm.define "server3" do |server3|
    //
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook1.yml"
  end
end
```

The above executes playbook1 on all servers. How can I add config for playbook2.yml to be executed only on server1 and AFTER playbook1?

Comment: Are the requirements as you stated, e.g. "`playbook1` should be executed on every server first. The second `playbook2` should only be executed on server1" or did I miss something because the solution you accepted results in `playbook1` being executed on server1 (not on server2 nor server3) and `playbook2` on server2 (not on server1 nor server3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example `Vagrantfile` and your theoretical `playbook2.yml` executing only on `server2` after `playbook1.yml` on `server1`, we would arrive at the following solution:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64" 

  config.vm.define "server1" do |server1|
    //
    # restrict scope of ansible provisioner to server1 by invoking on its class method off the constructor
    server1.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = 'playbook1.yml'
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "server2" do |server2|
    //
    # perform similarly for server2, which executes after server1 provisioning due to the imperative ruby dsl
    server2.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = 'playbook2.yml'
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "server3" do |server3|
    //
  end
end
```

It is also worth noting that if you want to be precise about ordering, you can `vagrant up server1` and then `vagrant up server2` instead of an all-in-one `vagrant up`.

Basically, within `Vagrant.configure` there is a scope affecting all VMs within `config.vm`. You can restrict its scope to specific VMs by instantiating with `config.vm.define` like you do above. Object VMs instantiated with `config.vm.define` have the same members/attributes as the base `config`.

Note you can also do something like this if you want:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  ...
  (1..3).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "server#{i}" do |server|
      //
      server.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "playbook#{i}.yml"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

for a per-server specific playbook. This depends on what exactly is within your `//` though specific to each VM, and if you wanted a third playbook for the third VM.

Answer (score 3):

The below example will execute `playbook1.yml` on every server first then execute  `playbook2.yml` only on server1 (this example assumes that the `playbook1.yml` can be parallelized):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  N = 3
  (1..N).each do |server_id|
    config.vm.define "server#{server_id}" do |server|
      server.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
      server.vm.hostname = "server#{server_id}"
      server.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.28.128.25#{server_id}"
      server.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sudo apt install -y python"
      # only execute once the ansible provisioner,
      # when all the machines are up and ready.
      if server_id == N
        server.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
          # disable default limit to connect to all the machines
          # execute playbook1 on all hosts
          ansible.limit = "all"
          ansible.playbook = "playbook1.yml"
          ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
        end
        server.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
          # limit the connection to server1 and execute playbook2
          ansible.limit = "server1"
          ansible.playbook = "playbook2.yml"
          ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This example builds on top of the example provided in the [Tips and Tricks](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html), the `ansible-playbook`'s are parallelized and the scope for both `ansible-playbooks`'s is limited by the `ansible.limit` configuration option (e.g. a `vagrant up` will bring up the virtual machines first then execute the playbooks one after the other against all hosts or subset of hosts).

**Note**: the `ubuntu/bionic64 (virtualbox, 20190131.0.0)` box has `/usr/bin/python3` installed, for the sake of having a copy & paste example and for using a dynamic inventory I deliberately kept the `server.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sudo apt install -y python"` in the example so `ansible-playbook (2.7.6)` doesn't bomb out with `"/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n` errors (ref. [How do I handle python not having a Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python on a remote machine?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html)). Example `playbook1.yml` and `playbook2.yml` (present in the same directory as the `Vagrantfile`):

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: 'executing on {{ inventory_hostname }}'
```

Results in:
[image]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!  I've been struggling for days to figure out how to run a post provisioning playbook and this has solved my problem.