# Using Vagrant to test ansible roles

Tags: ansible, vagrant

How do I restrict the scope of a playbook that references a role to the Vagrant image I have provisioned?

I have a playbook:

```
---
- name: Test Vagrant  
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  roles:
    - vagtest
```

This points to a role that simply installs the yum package tree.

My Vagrantfile is as follows:

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.7.0"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.playbook = "vagtest.yml"
  end
end
```

Now all works well - vagrant up / vagrant provision. I am concerned about 'hosts: all' in the playbook. Is there any way to restrict the scope of the playbook so that only my vagrant image is affected ? I am concerned that if the playbook is executed outside of vagrant that the test playbook will get executed across the whole environment.

Thanks.

Comment: You can limit the scope of `ansible` execution setting the `ansible.limit = "host"`, ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54470442/1423507 for a complete example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an ansible playbook on a specific vagrant host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468546/how-to-run-an-ansible-playbook-on-a-specific-vagrant-host)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [hosts/inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) file. In that host file point towards your vagrant image.

Then, change your `hosts: all` to `hosts: <what you provide in your host file>`

run with `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml`

Comment: Decided the best way to keep the Vagrant hosts separated from production is to run Ansible out of a separate subdirectory  - probably best practice to keep dev and pro separated anyway,